# How to add new group using JNDI to ApacheDS?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, apacheds

I tried

```
java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;

    public class Main{  


            public static void main(String[] args) {  

                 Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
                 env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
                 env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:10389");
                 env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
                 env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"uid=admin,ou=system"); // specify the username
                 env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"secret");// specify the password
                // TODO code application logic here  

                          // entry's DN 
           String entryDN = "cn=myadmins,ou=groups,ou=system";  

            // entry's attributes  

            Attribute cn = new BasicAttribute("cn", "myadmins");  
            Attribute oc = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");  
            oc.add("top");  
            oc.add("groupOfUniqueNames");   
            DirContext ctx = null;  

            try {  
                // get a handle to an Initial DirContext  
                ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);  

                // build the entry  
                BasicAttributes entry = new BasicAttributes();  
                entry.put(cn);  

                entry.put(oc);  

                // Add the entry  

                ctx.createSubcontext(entryDN, entry);  
      //          System.out.println( "AddUser: added entry " + entryDN + ".");  

            } catch (NamingException e) {  
                System.err.println("AddUser: error adding entry." + e);  
            }  
         }  
    }
```

Iam working on DS's example default schema.

But i get

```
Required attributes [uniqueMember(2.5.4.50)] not found within entry cn=myadmins,ou=groups,ou=system]; remaining name 'cn=myadmins,ou=groups,ou=system'
```

i looked at other group entry, it has `uniqueMember` attribute with value:

```
0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1=admin,2.5.4.11=system
```

How can i specify the uniqueMember attribute's value for my new group,

i must confess the number containing dots is a little complicated to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `uniqueMember` attribute has DN syntax. This means a distinguished name must be used as a value, not a relative distinguished name (or component of a distinguished name). A distinguished name is analogous to a fully-qualified pathname on a filesystem.

Think of the `uniqueMember` attribute value as a "pointer" to a distinguished name which is a member of the group.

Update:

The `the number containing dots` is an `OID`. Attributes, controls, and other things in LDAP use OIDs, for example, an attribute like `cn` has an OID associated with it that serves to uniquely identify it in the schema.

Comment: I think i have to specify one uniqueMember while defining new group. Thus how can i specify it? Do i have to take some parameters into account when specifying uniqueMember?

Comment: The `uniqueMember` is the distinguished name of an admin, if the name of the group is any indication.